# "kinds" or "species" in the sentence

Tags: questions

> Given sentence:
>
> Visitors  should  not  miss  the  beautiful  20  hectre  Jurong  Bird  Park  which  is  the  largest  bird park  in  all  of  South-east  Asia.  Home  to  over  8,000  birds  from  600  species,  the Jurong  Bird  Park  holds the distinction of  having  the world’s  tallest  man-made  waterfall.
>
> Question:
>
> How many **kinds of birds** are there in the Jurong Bird Park?
>
> Possible answer:
>
> 1. There are over 8000 birds from 800 species in the Jurong Bird Park.
> 2. There are 8000 species of birds in the Jurong Bird Park.

Which is suitable for the question?

Comment: *species* are scientific categories. *kinds* can be any distinction, such as *black birds* or *flightless birds*.

Comment: One who down-vote should add your reason.If so, I can improve my quedtion.

Comment: More detail or context is needed. As it stands, the answer so far indicates this could be answered using a dictionary. If that is not enough, you need to more detail as to what the confusion is.

Comment: Yes, I've edited.

Comment: The answer that you offered is factually incorrect:. there are billions of birds in the world, and there are about 10,000 species. Because if this, it is difficult to understand what kind of answer you want.

Comment: I tried again to improve my question Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. Check the definitions.

[Kind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kind)

> a group of people or things having similar characteristics.

[Species](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/species)

> a group of living organisms consisting of similar individuals capable of exchanging genes or interbreeding. The species is the principal natural taxonomic unit, ranking below a genus and denoted by a Latin binomial, e.g. Homo sapiens.

synonyms:   type, **kind**, sort

If you want to sound sophisticated, *species* is definitely a better option.